# VBA relative references

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and just learning how to use relative references.  I have an excel worksheet that will contain roughly 27 tables and I'll need to create 5 versions of this worksheet.  The output from the tool I'm using is not in the format that's needed.  Below is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

**Each of the tables in the worksheet will have a different number of rows**.  I've managed to get the code that bolds the question, centers the columns (from 'Total' to 'None') and highlights the different sections... but I can't get the code that bolds the row labels and percentages, or the row  labeled 'column name.'

Here is my code for the first part:

```
 Format Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1:E1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1:E1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 8).Range("A1:B1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Here's was my attempt to write the code for the bolding:

```
' Bold Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

I've included a link to a sample file for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in "relative referencing" where your problems lie but in referencing. Take this code.

```
Dim Ws As WorkSheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = Ws.Cells(1, "A").Resize(2, 10)
```

The code first declares two objects, meaning, names are given. This simple setup allows you to avoid all "Select" or "Activate" statements and does away with all references to the `ActiveSheet` or the `Selection` object. That's about half your code.

Having defined the worksheet and given it a name you can refer to any cell on it, like `Ws.Cells(13, "C").Font.Bold = True`. Note that Cells(13, "C") could also (better) be addressed as Cells(13, 3). You can change the name of that sheet, like `Ws.Name = "My New Name"` and still refer to it in your code as `Ws`. You can specify ranges in it as shown above, either by specifying an offset (as the `Resize` method does) or by simply specifying first and last cell.

```
Set Rng = Ws.Range("A1:C37")
or 
Set Rng = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, 1), Ws.Cells(37, "A"))
which would usually be written like this:-
With Ws
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(37, 1))
End With
```

You can also use the worksheet object to identify tables in the worksheet.

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects(1)
or
Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects("Table1")
```

That new object gives you access to all sorts of cells.

```
Set Rng = Tbl.DataBodyRange    ' all the data below the header row
Set Rng = Tbl.HeaderRowRange   ' the row with captions
Set Rng = Tbl.Range            ' all of the table
```

Within each range cells are accessible by their row and column or by their index number. `Tbl.Range.Cells(1)` is the same as `Tbl.Range.Cells(1, 1)` or `Tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1)`. Each of these cells has a Font object which has a Bold property which you can set without ever selecting anything. And you might still refer to any of them by their worksheet coordinates.

Enough. Please take it from here.